# Series - Let a(n) be an arithmetic sequence and, as usual let A(n)=a(1) + a(2) + ... + a(n). If A(5) = 50 and A(20) = 650, find A(15)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a(n) be an arithmetic sequence and, as usual let $A(n)=a(1) + a(2) + \dots + a(n).$ If $A(5) = 50$ and $A(20) = 650$, find $A(15).$

I'm not so sure how to solve that. 
So

Comment: You may wish to clarify when you mean sequence and when you mean series.  I assume that $A_{n}$ is a finite sum, and $a_{n}$ is an arithmetic sequence (not a series).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(n)$ be an arithmetic sequence, then:

$A(n)=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$

where $a$ is $A(1)$ and $d$ is the common difference.

Using the formula above we yield the system of 2 equations below:

$\frac{5}{2}(2a+4d)=50$

$\frac{20}{2}(2a+19d)=650$

Now with this two equations I can find $a$ and $d$, So I can now find $A(15)$ using the formula above.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using $d$ to denote the common difference between terms, we can see that the terms from $a_6$ to $a_{10}$ are each exactly $5d$ more than the terms from $a_1$ to $a_5$.

This means that 
$$\begin{align}A(10) &= 2A(5)+25d \\
\text{Similarly, }A(15) &= 3A(5)+75d \\
\text{ and } A(20) &=4A(5) + 150d
\end{align}$$
 Then it's  apparent that $A(15)= A(20)/2 + A(5) = 325+50=375$.

Of course you can also compute $d$ from this if you want to, but it isn't needed here.